# parse data from listitems to textview of facebook for sharing

Tags: android

how to parse data from listitems to the textview of facebook.
here is my code but it cant work, it only parse data to gmail, email textview .

> ```
>                 String text = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
> ```

```
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share text"));
```

k.